# Tableau: how to count by year?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau. I have a dataset with video games and the year they were released. I would like to make a distribution of the games released per year. 
The x-axis is the years, but the y-axis should be the count of the times that year was mentioned as the release date. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Is there also a nice way to make intervals for every 5 years instead of plotting all the years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you drag your [Release Date] to columns and the [Number of records] measure to rows, you will get exactly what you want.
If you want to group the years the easiest way would probably be to create a calculated field (right click on a dimension/create/calculated field) with the following formula:

```
div(year([date]),5) * 5
```

Which will give you the years from 1990-1994 as 1990 and so on.
If you drag this into columns instead of the release date you have your grouping.

Comment: Where do I put the div? so it use `DIV (year published([year]), 5)*5`
Also how can I cut off the diagram, because it continues even after 2017.

Comment: Ok I fixed the latter by excluding those values. But the question for div still stands :)

Comment: I assume the question is how to create a calculated field? I added it into the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the histogram bins feature in Tableau to easily combine nearby years into a single bin.

In the data pane on the left side bar, right click on your Year field and use the Create submenu to Create bins. This will create a new field called Year (bins) that maps year to bins (blocks) of years.

Right click on the Year (bins) field and set the bin size to 5 (or whatever number of years you prefer)

Now you can use Years (bin) on the column (or any other) shelf as you like. You can also change it from discrete to continuous if you like depending on how you want the data presented.

Comment: That only works if you create a calculated field YEAR([Date]) first. You can create a bin only on measures, not on dimensions. 
Had the idea as well but couldn't do it on [date]. The calc field solution just came to my mind and it works.

Comment: Many data sets have a numeric Year field which works fine, instead of a true date field. But as you say, you can extract the Year from a date with a calculated field if needed. The calculated field approach works as well.

Comment: BTW, you can create bins from any numeric type field, whether it is by default a measure or a dimension, discrete or continuous.

Comment: ah yea, sorry I assumed the year would be a date. Reading the question again, it sounds more likely that it is only the year.

Comment: It is a date. I, however, do not get the option to create bins. Only calculated field, group, set, parameter and custom date.

Comment: You can create a custom date - choose year and date part instead of date value. That will create a numeric year field that you can use to then create bins